# Which analysis should i use for group classification?

Tags: r, clustering, pca, data-visualization

I have done this PCA analysis and found the score values. Now I want to do another analysis on this data to see that PC loaded in which "Region" (column 1). Now used a NMDS plot using Bray-Curtis distance but it didn't work because of negative values in my data and Bray-Curtis does not accept negative values. Now which group based analysis and plot can I use for this data? All I want to show in a plot is similar to NMDS or a PCA biplot, where my group will be column 1, and all other PCs will be variables.

My data can be found in the following R code:

```
df = structure(list(Region = c("Nearshore", "Nearshore", "Nearshore", 
"Nearshore", "Nearshore", "Nearshore", "Open.Coast", "Open.Coast", 
"Open.Coast", "Open.Coast", "Open.Coast", "Open.Coast", "Open.Coast", 
"Open.Coast", "Open.Coast", "Enclosed.Coast", "Enclosed.Coast", 
"Enclosed.Coast", "Enclosed.Coast", "Enclosed.Coast", "Enclosed.Coast", 
"Enclosed.Coast", "Enclosed.Coast", "Enclosed.Coast"), PC1 = c(0.05155, 
0.72589, 4.51366, -0.2875, -0.33318, -0.24141, 0.45208, -0.43978, 
-0.33437, -0.10266, -0.43803, -0.06155, -0.33315, -0.43295, -0.32238, 
-0.26192, -0.13854, -0.29993, -0.15636, -0.31462, -0.2219, -0.20458, 
-0.40134, -0.41701), PC2 = c(4.62838, -0.002, -0.26033, -0.39012, 
0.04516, 0.03174, -0.36594, -0.17977, -0.17465, -0.4383, 0.04853, 
-0.30387, -0.40474, -0.28886, -0.30313, -0.43945, 0.15996, -0.14643, 
-0.20141, -0.11187, -0.233, -0.24889, -0.34155, -0.07946), PC3 = c(0.28943, 
-0.23337, 0.06436, 4.42991, -0.33704, 0.23142, -0.17771, -0.49233, 
-0.4514, 0.06364, -0.26328, -0.30234, 0.32302, -0.46234, -0.18357, 
-0.09561, -0.73065, -0.51259, -0.22714, -0.38594, -0.38553, -0.40491, 
0.7234, -0.47943), PC4 = c(0.29625, -0.87053, -0.52806, -0.13906, 
-0.29154, -1.11497, 4.2814, -0.37008, -0.16753, 0.92035, -0.04185, 
0.10405, 0.47559, -0.26294, -0.09731, -0.24304, -4e-05, -0.34034, 
-0.40021, -0.50831, -0.42983, -0.28641, -0.05559, 0.07003), PC5 = c(-0.12504, 
3.12896, -0.61621, -0.27948, -0.15022, -0.28804, 0.00585, -0.61353, 
-0.37799, -0.41793, 1.21376, -0.49828, 2.8628, -0.61283, -0.55436, 
-0.39319, 0.03439, -0.33033, -0.11746, -0.4883, -0.42609, 0.14161, 
-0.46233, -0.63575), PC6 = c(0.01596, 0.13053, -0.33099, -0.00258, 
-0.25482, 0.86949, 0.61772, -0.69354, -1.05855, -0.33978, -1.13565, 
-1.04981, -0.27423, -0.98407, -1.02406, 2.8498, 1.05188, -0.03267, 
2.03245, 0.66612, 0.49488, 0.12099, -0.75206, -0.91701)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```